# Http agility pack xpath

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a problem, I can not properly use the HTTP AGILITY package PACK, for example, wanting to retrieve the address of the image contained in the "style", I would like to know if someone suggests me to use xpath.

CODE HTML

```
<TABLE id=uezszu_24 class="uiGrid fbPhotosGrid" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
 <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD class="vTop">
      <DIV class=Wrapper>
       <A class="uiMediaThumb uiScrollableThumb uiMediaThumbHuge" href="www.cccc.com/index.php" 
        name=43563463 rel=theater aria-label="photo" ajaxify="dsgdgbdfgr45y6ghd">
        <I style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(http://www.fressdgf.com/image.jpg)"></I>
       </A>
      </DIV>
    </TD>
  </TR>
 </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

CODE VB

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim site As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
    Dim document As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = site.Load("https://www.site.com")
    For Each table As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")

        ListBox1.Items.Add(table.InnerText)

    Next
End Sub
```

Edited: Code indention improved

Comment: Do you want the contents of the style attribute? Or the actual uri in the style attribute? If the latter, you'll need to first fetch the attribute from the node. Then Parse the style block yourself. HTML Agility Pack doesn't parse it for you, it just sees the test. A regex might work here. 'background-image\s*:\s*url\s*\(\s*(?<url>[^)]+))' would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Linq instead XPath. If you want to obtain the background image of the  node inside the  you can do this:

```
For Each tableRow As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
    Dim italicNode As HtmlNode = tableRow.DescendantNodes().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "i")
    Dim styleValue As String = italicNode.GetAttributeValue("style",String.Empty)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(styleValue)
Next
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Descendants("i") is even better than .Where(Function(n) n.Name = "i".